# React checkbox doesn't keep toggled (think is in infinite loop)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, checkbox, infinite-loop, use-state

Basically i have this:

`const [searchUser, setSearchUser] = useState<string[]>([])`

Which i pass as a filter on an array:

```
reportsData
  .filter((value: any) =>
  searchUser.length > 0
  ? searchUser.includes(value.user.name)
  : true
  )
```

And i created checkboxes that passes values to this `searchUser` state so i can filter my array with one (or multiple checkboxes)
Like this:

```
const EmittersComponent: React.FC<PropsButton> = ({ label, onSelect }) => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

    function handleSelect() {
      onSelect(label)
      setChecked(!checked)
    }

    return (
      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-3 lg:grid-cols-2">
        <li className="mt-4 flex items-start">
          <div className="flex items-center h-5">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={() => {
                setChecked(checked)
                handleSelect()
              }}
              checked={checked}
              className="h-4 w-4 focus:bg-indigo border-2 border-gray-300 rounded"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="ml-3 text-sm">
            <span className="font-medium text-gray-700">
              {label || 'Sem nome'}
            </span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
    )
  }

  function handleToggle(label: string) {
    setSearchUser((prev) =>
      prev.some((item) => item === label)
        ? prev.filter((item) => item !== label)
        : [...prev, label]
    )
  }

  const emittersComponent = () => (
    <div>
      {emittersData.map((value: any, index: any) => (
        <EmittersComponent
          key={index}
          label={value.Attributes[2]?.Value}
          onSelect={handleToggle}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
```

Then i render it on my react component `<ul>{emittersComponent()}</ul>`

But the thing is, it is working everything correctly (if i select one or multiple checkboxes, it filters my array), but the checkbox won't keep toggled. It will render as if it was untoggled (the blank, unchecked box) no matter what i do.

I think is in an infinite loop and i can't fix it.

Comment: You have to lift the state up and manage the isChecked logic. Can you include the Component that has setSearchUser state and where you call {emittersComponent()}

Comment: I put the whole component here (cause it is big and stackoverflow doesn't let it): https://pastebin.com/eeXPDFMG

Answer (score 0):

You have called `setChecked` in the

```
onChange={() => {
  setChecked(checked)
  handleSelect()
}}
```

and then `setChecked` is calling inside `handleSelect` function. That is not correct.

I assume it should be `onChange={handleSelect}`

Comment: I changed that and it still doesn't keep toggled. (It actually was like this before, but i was trying everything lol then it ended up the way i put on the post)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a component inside another component with its own state, therefore a emittersComponent is created in every render.

Move Emitters component and emittersComponent(changed to EmittersComponentList ) function out of Quick Sight Component.

Try the below if this doesnt work then you have to have a logic to know which of the emittersData is checked.

```
const EmittersComponentList = ({ emittersData, handleToggle }) => (
  <div>
    {emittersData.map((value: any, index: any) => (
      <EmittersComponent
        key={value.Attributes[2]?.Value} // Dont add index as the key, add some unique val
        label={value.Attributes[2]?.Value}
        onSelect={handleToggle}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);

const EmittersComponent: React.FC<PropsButton> = ({ label, onSelect }) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  function handleSelect() {
    onSelect(label);
    setChecked(!checked);
  }

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-3 lg:grid-cols-2">
      <li className="mt-4 flex items-start">
        <div className="flex items-center h-5">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={() => {
              setChecked(checked);
              handleSelect();
            }}
            checked={checked}
            className="h-4 w-4 focus:bg-indigo border-2 border-gray-300 rounded"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="ml-3 text-sm">
          <span className="font-medium text-gray-700">
            {label || "Sem nome"}
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
}
```

;

In your Quick Sight Component

```
 <div className="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 lg:gap-6">
            <div>
              <span className="text-xl font-medium text-accent-9">
                Escolha os emissores:
              </span>
              <ul>
                {
                  /* Instead of emittersComponent()
                             use below                           
                           */
                  <EmittersComponentList
                    emittersData={emittersData}
                    handleToggle={handleToggle}
                  />
                }
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
```

Comment: It simply messed all of my stuff.
Everything with `setSearchUser` was giving me errors and so on and so on.
Says it should be used inside of a top-level function etcetera.